# creating a logical panda series by comparing two series

Tags: pandas

In pandas I'm trying to get two series combined to one logical one

```
f = pd.Series(['a','b','c','d','e'])
x = pd.Series(['a','c'])
```

As a result I would like to have the series

```
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

I tried

```
f.map(lambda e: e in x)
```

Series f is large (30000) so looping over the elements (with `map`) is probably not very efficient. What would be a good approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin):

```
In [207]:
f = pd.Series(['a','b','c','d','e'])
x = pd.Series(['a','c'])
f.isin(x)

Out[207]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

You can convert the dtype using [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas.Series.astype) if you prefer:

```
In [208]:
f.isin(x).astype(int)

Out[208]:
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    0
dtype: int32
```